# When StackOverflow community fails to answer, who/where would you post your question again?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

I see a lot of questions on Stack Overflow that receive good bunch of votes for asking, but no body comments or answers them. This has happened to me as well a couple of times.

The stream of questions on Stack Overflow is superfast and many a times the questions just go unanswered.

What does Stack Overflow do about the interesting Unanswered Questions?
What ideas would you give to Stack Overflow to help answer these interesting unanswered questions?
I have very less reputation as of now, and I don't want to bounty my questions. People having less than 75 reputation cannot even offer bounty their question.

P.S.: This might be a very subjective question, but I want to make it a helpful one for people like me who don't know where to post an unanswered question. Please support this and don't vote for closing the matter. Also it is not a duplicate of [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)
I am speaking about interesting unanswered questions and not all unanswered questions.

Comment: I have at least a couple of questions that fell into that category. I even announced a bounty once and somebody grabbed it by asking me for more clarification as his answer. One thing that might help though is to improve your answer acceptance rate.

Comment: "Interesting questions" is rather subjective; there isn't then any difference between getting attention on unanswered questions, and getting attention on interesting unanswered questions.

Comment: I just had a look at your unanswered questions and noticed [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389345/google-interview-question-recursive-query-or-common-table-expression-for-the-fol) If it had included code to create and populate the tables I probably would have answered it now but I always find that tedious and just decided not to bother. My suggestion for that one would be too include this so potential answerers don't have to spend their time doing it.

Answer (score 5):

If the community fails to answer, you may want to take another look at your question.

Is it clear? Is it useful? Can it be answered? Take a look at [these guidelines](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) to see if it can be improved.

If you think it can be, edit it to get the question back to the front pages.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your question as a way to bump your question up. The edit should clarify the question, and/or offer new information from your own research. What do you do before SO exists then :D